# How to reset value of multiple dictionaries elegantly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code which pulls data from database and based on the different type of tables , store the data in dictionary for further usage.
This code handles around 20-30 different table so there are 20-30 dictionaries and few lists which I have defined as class variables for further usage in code.
for example.

```
class ImplVars(object):
    #dictionary capturing data from Asset-Feed table
    general_feed_dict = {}
    ports_feed_dict = {}
    vulns_feed_dict = {}
    app_list = []
    ...
```

I want to clear these dictionaries before I add data in it.
Easiest or common way is to use clear() function but this code is repeatable as I will have to write for each dict.
Another option I am exploring is with using dir() function but its returning variable names as string.

Is there any elegant method which will allow me to fetch all these class variables and clear them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use introspection as you suggest:

```
for d in filter(dict.__instancecheck__, ImplVars.__dict__.values()):
    d.clear()
```

Or less cryptic, covering lists and dicts:

```
for obj in ImplVars.__dict__.values():
    if isinstance(obj, (list, dict)):
        obj.clear()
```

But I would recommend you choose a bit of a different data structure so you can be more explicit:

```
class ImplVars(object):
    data_dicts = {
        "general_feed_dict": {},
        "ports_feed_dict": {},
        "vulns_feed_dict": {},
    }
```

Now you can explicitly loop over `ImplVars.data_dicts.values` and still have other class variables that you may not want to clear.

Comment: modified the code a little bit as list doesn't have clear ()

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
a_dict = {1:2}
b_dict = {2:4}
c_list = [3,6]

vars_copy = vars().copy()
for variable, value in vars_copy.items():
    if variable.endswith("_dict"):
        vars()[variable] = {}
    elif variable.endswith("_list"):
        vars()[variable] = []
print(a_dict)
print(b_dict)
print(c_list)
```

result:

```
{}
{}
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the easier kinds of implementation would be to create a list of dictionaries and lists you want to clear and later make the loop clear them all.

```
d = [general_feed_dict, ports_feed_dict, vulns_feed_dict, app_list]
for element in d:
    element.clear()
```

You could also use list comprehension for that.

Comment: I thought of this as well but I will have to maintain additional list along with dictionaries in case there are additions/removals in the class variables. 
Thank you for response.